# Are there statistics or time series of open bugs in Ubuntu?

Tags: launchpad, ubuntu-bug

I would like to know how the number of bugs in Ubuntu (open, closed, critical, etc) has evolved with time. It's a sort of scientific curiosity I have, but it would also give me a feeling how the community has changed over time, how it has coped with the challenges (I think of Unity in particular) and what's its status now.

Has anyone collected these data over the years? If yes, are they publicly available?

I know this information can be gathered from Launchpad itself and actually I found a [website](http://outflux.net/ubuntu/stats/) that had data from mid 2008 to early 2009. I found [Ubuntu live stats](http://ubuntustats.com/), which shows live messages related to Ubuntu, but does not aggregate bug statistics. Finally there are some stats on the [Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=243) but they only show diffs of bugs closed during the last week.

Comment: You should probably seek an answer at [launchpad answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad) -- it shouldn't be hard for some admin to query the creation date for all the bugs. The problem is to find an admin or a person with access willing to do that. Give them a good reason, besides curiosity. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean solution would be to query launchpad using the [launchpadlib](https://launchpad.net/launchpadlib) Python API, which wraps the API of the Launchpad webservice. Specifically, the [bug_task entry](https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/1.0.html#bug_task) contains all relevant information to reconstruct the history of any bug in ubuntu. One should just be careful not to query the whole database in one sweep since it is huge! Except for that, it should be straightforward to code it and get the statistics on closed/open bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong about the stats published in Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter. The numbers between the (brackets) is the actual number of current bugs.

The latest UWN stats:

> Bug Stats
>   Open (94461) -60 over last week
>   Critical (71) +4 over last week
>   Unconfirmed (48716) +136 over last week

UWN #36, April 8-14, 2007

> Bug Stats
>   Open (27504) +584 # over last week
>   Critical (17) -7 # over last week
>   Unconfirmed (13370) +404 # over last week
>   Unassigned (20041) +508 # over last week
>   All bugs ever reported (93592) +2010 # over last week

Comment: Thank you for pointing out meaning of the numbers in the brackets, I don't know why I had overlooked it. Could you rephrase your answer in a way that it actually answers my question? Otherwise just leave a comment below the question itself.